# How to join 3 collections into the same gallery?

Tags: powerapps-collection

How do I join 3 collections into the same gallery in PowerApps ?[image: All galleries have a filter function]

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough information to answer the question.

But guessing on what you want:

Lets say you have data source JOB_III and JOB_IV where JOB_III has a column named JobName, if JOB_IV has a column named JobName as well but some other info, you can use:

First(
Filter(
JOB_IV,
JobName = ThisItem.JobName
)
).JobSalary

This will get you the salary from the JOB_IV table nested in the gallery of JOB_III

G'Luck!